# Excel workbook linking

Tags: excel

I've created the following formula to pull data into my spreadsheet from a file in a different folder on the network. The formula works when the target spreadsheet is open and returns a value of 7. When the target spreadsheet is closed, the cell immediately changes to a #VALUE! error.

```
=COUNTIF('\\C\s\CAF1\DMBSU\Continuous Improvement\Registers\[Successes.xlsx]Success Register'!$B$12:$B$1000,">" & TODAY()-365)
```

Other formulas in my spreadsheet link to different files within the Registers folder without a problem. I have tried saving the target file as both .xls and .xlsx formats and neither resolves the problem.

I think this might be something to do with the security settings in the target file but cant work out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer on the Microsoft support pages. It can be fixed using a combination of SUM() and IF() as shown here: [SUMIF, COUNTIF and COUNTBLANK functions return "#VALUE!"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/260415/sumif-countif-and-countblank-functions-return-value-error)

The link in that page to help on using this solution for COUNTIFS and SUMIFS is broken however I found an alternative page here: [How to use a logical AND or OR in a SUM+IF statement in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/267982/how-to-use-a-logical-and-or-or-in-a-sum-if-statement-in-excel)

This has resolved the issue for me, by using array formulas as described within these pages.